# Capturing JsonParseException within application code of Play Framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, jackson

I have a Play framework application that gets JSON POSTed to it.

It's quite important that we log all invalid data on one particular call as errors for our internal monitoring.

I've managed to find a scenario the slips through my try/catches.

If you have invalid JSON where some double quotes haven't been escaped

```
{
   "key": "broken "value""
}
```

you get an exception thrown outside of the action method

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('M' (code 77)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
at [Source: [B@75618a1f; line: 32, column: 43]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1419) ~[jackson-core-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:508) ~[jackson-core-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:437) ~[jackson-core-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:680) ~[jackson-core-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at play.api.libs.json.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JsValue.scala:408) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.libs.json.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JsValue.scala:360) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.libs.json.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JsValue.scala:355) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3023) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.1.1.jar:2.4.1.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1637) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.1.1.jar:2.4.1.1]
at play.api.libs.json.JacksonJson$.parseJsValue(JsValue.scala:482) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.libs.json.Json$.parse(Json.scala:30) ~[play-json_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse$$anonfun$tolerantJson$1.apply(ContentTypes.scala:365) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse$$anonfun$tolerantJson$1.apply(ContentTypes.scala:361) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse$$anonfun$tolerantBodyParser$1$$anonfun$27$$anonfun$apply$79.apply(ContentTypes.scala:866) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:103) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:125) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse$$anonfun$tolerantBodyParser$1$$anonfun$27.apply(ContentTypes.scala:865) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse$$anonfun$tolerantBodyParser$1$$anonfun$27.apply(ContentTypes.scala:864) [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:471) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:471) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
```

Which you can see logs out as a debug message from this point

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/92078f9cc751a5c19117dede18c7ca63aca73347/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/ContentTypes.scala#L869

But I have no idea how I can catch this myself, log it out as an error (and log out the invalid request body

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/bh7MU9_AFsQ it looks like it might not be possible - wondered if anyone had any further ideas?

For reference my action method is as follows

```
def createTransaction =
withUser { auth => request =>
  request.body.asJson.map { json =>
    unmarshallTransactionResource(json, (resource: Transaction) => {
      try {
        if (auth.device.isDefined) {
          val id = transactionService.createTransactionForDevice(resource, auth.device.get)
          if (id.isDefined) {
            val transResp = TransactionResponse(id.get)
            Created(Json.toJson(transResp))
          } else {
            Logger.error("Failed transaction insert: " + json.toString())
            Conflict
          }
        } else {
          Forbidden
        }
      } catch {
        case unknown: Throwable  => Logger.error("Exception thrown handling transaction: " + unknown.getMessage + " JSON: "+ json.toString())
          BadRequest
      }
    })
  }.getOrElse{
    Logger.error("Failed transaction json decode: " + request.body.asText)
    BadRequest
  }
}
```

Comment: This exception is caused by the body parser trying to read a json value. You might want to use a custom body parser to log the failed parsing or you can override the play [`DefaultHttpErrorHandler`](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler) (cf. [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHttpRequestHandlers)) and log the exception there.